# Python Comptypes Error 'Invalid sized array passed to xxx'

Tags: python, invalid-argument, comtypes

I'm using Comtypes in Python. I'm newbe in Python.
The COM object I'am using in Comtypes in Python works well in Excel VBA.
The syntaxes of the COM object that I try to use in Python work like this in VBA:

```
object.mymethode1(vba_array_of_defined_size) 'it takes as argument of an array of defined size then does something else 
object.mymethode2(vba_array_of_defined_size) 'it takes as argument of an array of defined size then change directly the value of this array
```

I try to use the same syntaxe in Python with Comtypes, but none of the two methodes works

Below the error message:

```
COMError: (-2147221503, 'Invalid advise flags', ('Invalid sized array passed to mymethode', 'com_object_name', None, 1000440, None))
```

Anyone has any idea ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Forget to mention there is some encoding issue with the library to be used in Python, but that's kind of resolved. Other methods of the library works with in Python with Comtypes

Comment: I've also tried the method mentioned in the documentation of Comtypes to convert the array type like this : pt = array.array('d', [0,0,0]). Then use pt in my method. But still does not work.

Comment: also tried to convert the python array to pandas.dataframe then put pandas.dataframe into the methods. and still does not work

Comment: Can you provide the code that you're using? I would recommend pandas or numpy across the board if it fits you're use case, but what code are you trying to run?

Comment: Problem resolved. For my case, python need a list ( ). And the size of the list has to be the size of the array in excel + 1. If the array in excel contains 5 elements, then I have to use a list of 6 elements in python.